# Why is running an API on localhost so much slower than on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm a new Java developer and I've been developing a small app for tracking my runners' mileage at our school. The back end is in Java and the most intense operation for the server is getting the list of all the teammates, then finding the sum of their mileage for the last week and ranking them in order from highest to lowest. When I make a call to this endpoint while running on localhost, this took 11.5 seconds! I found with parallel streams it dropped the time to about 8.5 seconds, but I was still nervous that this was way too long. I uploaded the new JAR to the AWS EC2 instance and it takes less than a second! So my question is, why is my localhost (quad-core i7 7600k with 16 gb ram) so much slower than the AWS EC2 instance for the same operation? The EC2 instance connects to an RDS instance running MySql btw. Thanks!

Comment: Where is your data stored? Is it in a database on AWS?

Comment: How many teammates and separate mileage datapoints?

Comment: What type of AWS EC2 instance do you have? Do you connect with the remote RDS instance from your local machine?

Comment: When you're running it on localhost, are there any other dependencies such as Database etc. that are not on localhost? Please add details to your question to help other users understand and help you better.

Comment: I'm running on the t2.micro instance, 8GiB, region is us-east-2 and my database is in AWS relational database running MySql. There are approximately 40 teammates on the main team but I have a couple "test" teams with about 5 users that are also tabulated at that time.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes, I connect to the RDS instance from my local machine when testing/debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same issue. It's probably the round trip time, rather than processing time. My laptop is in the UK, and all my AWS services are in us-east-1.

One 'action' in application might involve several trips to AWS services, for example sending a token to Cognito, getting some data from DynamoDB, then getting some more data based on the first response etc etc. It all involves several round trips from the UK to the US. Your server is probably co-located with the services you call so much less RTT.

Comment: I thought this might be the case, but I live in the midwest ("flyover zone of America") so I'm much closer to all of my AWS services and didn't think the difference would be that large!

Comment: If you want to investigate further, you could create a timer for different parts of your process and print them to the log, then compare local and your server. Well done on your project anyway, sounds like you've done a great job for a new developer.